# Is it posible to declare global function in namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am making a resource system that similar to Qt's qrc.

The resource is automatically created to .c file contains byte array. And it compiled to static library.

And it has a header file looks like below. I don't know which hash value comes so I defined a macro function.

```
#ifndef BRC_6c26e83425a54300d410b49c1aa1c3ea
#define BRC_6c26e83425a54300d410b49c1aa1c3ea

void bl_register_resource_6c26e83425a54300d410b49c1aa1c3ea();

#ifdef BL_REGISTER_RESOURCE
    #undef BL_REGISTER_RESOURCE
#endif
#define BL_REGISTER_RESOURCE() \
    bl_register_resource_6c26e83425a54300d410b49c1aa1c3ea();

#endif
```

It is intended to use as

```
void init_function()
{
    #include "path/to/resource/resource.h"
    BL_REGISTER_RESOURCE()

    // Resource is registered in global singleton object
    // and now I can access the resource from it.

    #include "path/to/resource/another.h"
    BL_REGISTER_RESOURCE()

    // Another resource register function is called.
}
```

It worked find when I use C. But the code base has moved to C++, now I can't use this trick because include and call macro function may happened in C++ namespace.

```
namespace my {

MyClass::MyClass()
{
    #include "path/to/resource/resource.h"
    BL_REGISTER_RESOURCE()
}

} // namespace my
```

I found that I can't use extern "C" in function definition. The function declaration `void bl_register_resource_HASH();` will be `my::bl_register_resource_HASH();` but the function definition has no namespace. This causes "undefined reference to my::bl_register_resource_HASH()".

Include the header outside of namespace works fine. But in this time I can't use multiple macro call trick.

I tried `void ::bl_register_resource_HASH();` but it doesn't worked.

Is there any way to declare global scope function in namespace?

Answer (score 1):

I see the only simple way is

```
#ifndef BRC_6c26e83425a54300d410b49c1aa1c3ea
#define BRC_6c26e83425a54300d410b49c1aa1c3ea

void bl_register_resource_6c26e83425a54300d410b49c1aa1c3ea();

#endif

#ifdef BL_REGISTER_RESOURCE
    #undef BL_REGISTER_RESOURCE
#endif
#define BL_REGISTER_RESOURCE() \
    ::bl_register_resource_6c26e83425a54300d410b49c1aa1c3ea();
```

And usage

```
#include "path/to/resource/resource.h"
#include "path/to/resource/other.h"

namespace my {

MyClass::MyClass()
{
    #include "path/to/resource/resource.h"
    BL_REGISTER_RESOURCE()

    #include "path/to/resource/other.h"
    BL_REGISTER_RESOURCE()
}

}
```

I have moved `#endif` to make repeated `#include` being able to define the macro `BL_REGISTER_RESOURCE()`

Function like macros require special settings in clang-format. It is better

```
#define BL_REGISTER_RESOURCE() \
    ::bl_register_resource_6c26e83425a54300d410b49c1aa1c3ea()

BL_REGISTER_RESOURCE();
```